# How to write/read data in NSPasteboard?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How to write data (image files type like .gif, .jpg, .tiff, etc) to NSPasteboard? And how to extract data from NSPasteboard?

Comment: Please indicate what you have tried and what specifically you are having a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

Simply as that, start here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008099